# While I can edit font-color, I can't edit font-family

Tags: css, google-chrome, developer-tools, web-inspector

To ready my ebook more precisely, I want to edit font of some areas.
But I have an issue that while I can edit `color`, I can't edit `font-family` which is strikedout.
Further, there is same tag area which is not editable and is of same tag name as in second part that I mention as uneditable.

[image]

Comment: Because it uses `!important` so the style can't be changed, either remove the `!important` from the below one, or add `!important` to the above one

Comment: @Kyojimaru please write is as an answer, I want to accept it since you are first writer.

Comment: You can accept the answer below, same answer just a small time difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be "overwritten" by the font-family down because of `!important` flag.
remove the `!important` and the font itself and it should work.